# Can not edit Doctrine ArrayCollection

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine, persistent, arraycollection

I have a problem with editing an Doctrine2 ArrayCollection of a many-to-many assosciation.
Persisting an new entity is no problem and works fine. But if I would like to persist an entity with new added CollectionItems I got an

> Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException

I use the xml-mapping, the mapping files are the following:

receipt:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="Application\Entity\Receipt" table="receipt" repository-class="Application\Repositories\ReceiptRepository">
        <indexes>
            <index name="FK_receipt_profession" columns="professsion"/>
            <index name="FK_receipt_items_needed" columns="items"/>
        </indexes>
        <id name="rId" type="integer" column="r_id">
            <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
        </id>
        <field name="name" type="string" column="name" length="100" nullable="false"/>
        <many-to-one field="profession" target-entity="Application\Entity\Profession">
            <join-columns>
                <join-column name="profession" referenced-column-name="p_id"/>
            </join-columns>
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-many field="items" target-entity="Application\Entity\ItemsNeeded" inversed-by="receipt">
            <!--<cascade><cascade-all/></cascade>-->
            <join-table name="receipt_x_items_needed">
                <join-columns>
                    <join-column name="receipt" referenced-column-name="r_id"/>
                </join-columns>
                <inverse-join-columns>
                    <join-column name="itemNeeded" referenced-column-name="in_id"/>
                </inverse-join-columns>
            </join-table>
        </many-to-many>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

ItemsNeeded:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="Application\Entity\ItemsNeeded" table="items_needed" repository-class="Application\Repositories\ItemsneededRepository">
    <indexes>
      <index name="FK_items_needed_receipt" columns="receipt_id"/>
      <index name="item_id" columns="item_id"/>
    </indexes>
    <id name="inId" type="integer" column="in_id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="count" type="integer" column="count" nullable="false"/>
    <many-to-one field="item" target-entity="Application\Entity\Items">
      <join-columns>
        <join-column name="item_id" referenced-column-name="i_id"/>
      </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>
      <many-to-many field="receipt" target-entity="Application\Entity\Receipt" mapped-by="items"/>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

and items:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="Application\Entity\Items" table="items" repository-class="Importer\Repository\ItemRepository">
        <unique-constraints>
            <unique-constraint name="buffed_id" columns="buffed_id"/>
        </unique-constraints>
        <id name="iId" type="integer" column="i_id">
            <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
        </id>
        <field name="name" type="string" column="name" length="100" nullable="false"/>
        <field name="buffedId" type="integer" column="buffed_id" nullable="false"/>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

The receipt table has an many-to-many relation through the crosstable "receipt_x_items_needed".

If I call `$receipt->addItem($item);` and $item is an already existing item from the itemtable I got the following error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'Application\Entity\ItemsNeeded#item' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: Application\Entity\Items@0000000041f6e49000000000651183aa. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'Application\Entity\Items#__toString()' to get a clue.

But this is no new entity. All data are correctly set and as I wrote, if I add e new receipt all works fine.

Comment: I solved the problem. Every entity of an ArrayCollection is seen as a new one so it will write it into the database. The only option is to iterate over the Collection,load the entity and replace the entity in the Collection.                     If someone has an better option, please tell it :)